# Acquia stack / Wamp slow on response

Tags: performance

I am developing a site on my localhost. I used WAMP but it takes too long to load pages from time to time. Something like 20 seconds execution time according to devel. Not on every page, not every time, but happens often enough to disrupt any kind of work I am trying to do.
After no much success in debugging the problem I decided to try "DAMP" the Acquia stack for Drupal.

The difference is enormous- execution time is less than 1000 ms, which although much is something workable for dev. stage; Memory used peaks at 12 MB instead of 50 in wamp.

Still there is this problem of pages not loading fully. When I click on a link the browser shows that it is "connecting" and it will stay like that indefinitely (takes more than 2 minutes to time out), but if I interrupt and refresh the page loads instantly (100-300 ms)
This again would be acceptable if it didn't interfere with my work. I can't add or delete content because of this. It just stays on "connecting" and on refresh it hasn't made the action.

So my question is what makes acquia stack not finishing the page loads and wamp server to be so damn slow?

I am talking about drupal 7, hardware shouldn't be an issue (Core 2 duo at 3.1 Ghz, and 3 GB RAM, somewhat old, but still kicking)

Comment: Install an OP Cache (APC, etc), disable DBlog (enable syslog module if Windows is able to support), ensure cron jobs are scheduled and automated.  This should take care of the 20sec load times.

Comment: database logging and statistics are both disabled. I will make sure to work on the cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank both Citricguy and MauiTechSpot for directing my attention to Cron failing.

The site uses apache solr server and turns out that during some actions ( cron and deleting content ) Acquia-Drupal stack tries to connect to it. If it isn't turned on, Drupal will be waiting for connection indefinitely. This wasn't the case with my WAMP setup so I had the habit of fiddling around without turning on solr. As you can see it took me obscene amount of time to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

The WAMP issue sounds like CRON was not configured properly on a low traffic development site.  All of your scheduled tasks were likely backing up and running only when you loaded your site manually.

As for DAMP, do all php pages never complete or only Drupal?  Also, do static pages complete or time out?

Comment: To answer your two questions I used my drupal frontpage and saved it as an html file from the browser (made it a static page). I saved it inside a subfolder of my installation and accessed it through http://localhost:8082/folder/file.htm and it loaded completely. I then renamed the file to .php and added some simple for function that did some output. File run fine, page loaded fully. In the mean time drupal dynamic front page still hasn't loaded.

Comment: Can you give me some directions about configuring CRON properly on a low traffic development site? CRON at least runs on WAMP. I saw that it hasn't run a single time in DAMP, trying to do a manual run gives me a message "Cron run failed."

Comment: Configuring cron jobs on Windows: http://drupal.org/node/31506